# Jquery .fancybox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

So on this page [here](http://dunnrite.co.uk/our_work), the image at the top of the "Clubz4u" website when clicked is supposed to show an enlarged image preview done with jquery's fancybox function. But it just opens the image.

Here is my code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Stylesheets/script.js"></script>
    <!--<style>#content_box {height:950px;}</style>-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dunnrite.co.uk/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dunnrite.co.uk/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dunnrite.co.uk/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>

        <div id="left_side_work">
                <h3>Our Work</h3>
                <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="Images/Clubz4u.jpg">
                    <div id="clubz4u_pic"></div>
                </a>
                <a target="blank" href="http://beauxcadeaux.co.uk">
                    <div id="beaux_cadeaux_pic"></div>
                </a>
        </div>
```

`

Comment: Check your console, fancybox is missing or url is wrong.

Comment: How many times are you using the actual jquery library? You only need it once.

Comment: re: above comment - pick a version.

Comment: I wasn't sure which library to use so I picked a few. Which one shall I keep? And where is my console? Which url?

Comment: Use latest jQuery version and remove the rest. And for example this url is 404: http://dunnrite.co.uk/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5

Comment: Which one is the latest? Do you know what the correct url is?

Answer (score 0):

mijopabe is right. you have 4 versions of jQuery loaded which will cause all sorts of problems. Use just one instance of jQuery and that should help.

Comment: Will not since fancybox is not present.

Comment: ahhh so it is. I was only going off the code he posted. My bad